# How to open pdf in a popup in php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, pdf, popup

Basically I am using BSK PDF Manager Plugin in Wordpress and want to open the the pdfs in a popup when someone click them.

```html
 
 /* This is the href code of the plugin and what I tried to open 
 
$pdf_title_str = '<a href="'.esc_url($file_url).'"'.esc_attr($open_target_str.$nofollow_tag_str).'  title="'.esc_attr($pdf_item_obj_title).'" class="bsk-pdfm-pdf-link-for-title pdf-id-'.esc_attr($pdf_item_obj->id).'">'.$pdf_title_str.'</a>';
```

Comment: Use javascript instead, put link into `data-attribute` then `onClick` event open a popup of link.

Comment: I'd say, add a `target` attribute, and be done with it. "Custom" popups with dimensions specified by the website author are an anachronism, modern browsers allow users to specify that they only want to open new, full-size tabs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$filePath = 'file/example.pdf';

if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
    echo "The file $filePath does not exist";
    die();
}

$filename="example.pdf";
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
header('Accept-Ranges:bytes');

readfile($filePath);
?>
```

you can try with this code

Comment: This get back the pdf from PHP, but it *not* open a popup and show the PDF as ask.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with what @CBroe suggested: update your code with `target` to open the link (your PDF) in a new window/tab:

```
$pdf_title_str = '<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url($file_url) . '"' . esc_attr($open_target_str . $nofollow_tag_str) . '  title="' . esc_attr($pdf_item_obj_title) . '" class="bsk-pdfm-pdf-link-for-title pdf-id-' . esc_attr($pdf_item_obj->id) . '">' . $pdf_title_str . '</a>';
```